# I am trying to insert a sprite image into pygame window and it wont pop up

Tags: python, pygame

(i followed a yt tut so idk) my code: idk if i put code in wrong place

```
import pygame
   
 white = (255,255,255)
 black = (0,0,0)
 orange = (255,165,0) 
 player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png") .convert_alpha


 pygame.init()
 display = pygame.display.set_mode((850,850))
 pygame.display.set_caption('Conners Game')

 exit = False

while not exit:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        exit = True
    print(event)

display.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

not really sure why it does this, im new to python so idk

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you actually have it. Indentation is crucial in Python, and what you show currently would be a syntax error.

Comment: That said: what part of your code is intended to cause the sprite to appear? (Hint: each time through the loop, what gets drawn onto `display`?) Also: if you are "new to python" then you should follow a tutorial and make sure you understand the language fundamentals, before trying to use something more sophisticated like Pygame.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image in the application loop, after clearing the display and before updating the display:

```py
display.blit(player_sprite, (100, 100))
```

[`convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) is function. You missed the parentheses

<s>`player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png").convert_alpha`</s>

```py
player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png").convert_alpha()
```

Also, you cannot call a pygame function before you initialize pygame. `pygame.init()` should be the very first pygame function called.

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
   
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
orange = (255,165,0) 

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((850,850))
pygame.display.set_caption('Conners Game')

player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png").convert_alpha()
exit = False
while not exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
        print(event)

    display.fill(white)
    display.blit(player_sprite, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that needs to fixed. First of all to you actually need to [blit](https://realpython.com/lessons/using-blit-and-flip/) the image on the screen.

```py
while not exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #...[block of code]

    display.fill(white)
    display.blit(player_sprite, (100,100)) # BLIT IMAGE TO SCREEN
```

`.convert_alpha()` is a method and you need to call it after you initialize pygame and set the video mode.

You can read more about `convert_alpha()` [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)

```py
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((850,850))
pygame.display.set_caption('Conners Game')

#converting it after init and setting game mode

player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png").convert_alpha()
```

Here's the final working code

```
import pygame
   
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
orange = (255,165,0) 



pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((850,850))
pygame.display.set_caption('Conners Game')
player_sprite = pygame.image.load("will smith.png").convert_alpha()
exit = False

while not exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
        # print(event)

    display.fill(white)
    display.blit(player_sprite, (100,100))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```